# NSUrlConnection and cURl

Tags: ios, http, post, curl, nsurlconnection

I'm new to NSUrlConnection. I have this cUrl:

```
curl -X POST 
 -H "Authorization: Basic someReallyLongCode"  
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
 -d '{ "Payment": { "TotalAmount": 100 }, "RedirectURL": "https://www.mydomain.com.au/results?order=0001" }' 
 https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/AccessCodes
```

Is this code correct in Objective C?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/AccessCodes"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"Basic someReallyLongCode" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

NSString *stringData = @"{ \"Payment\": { \"TotalAmount\": 100 }, \"RedirectURL\": \"https://www.mydomain.com.au/results?order=0001\" }";
[request setHTTPBody:[stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

a = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work? Stackoverflow does not replace the debugging. - (Remark: have a look at NSJSONSerialization)

Comment: It should be correct. However, in real code, you may face the following potential problems: composing a JSON string "by hand" may be error prone, better construct a JSON compatible `NSDictionary` and use `NSJSONSerialization` in order to obtain the JSON string (as a `NSData` object). Also, setting up the query component of your embedded URL may have more subtleties than you may think of - given that you possibly need to properly percent escape the parameters. Better you use some utilities, which know exactly how to compose a URL query parameter string out of a `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Thanks Problem Solved!!! The sintaxis is correct, it was a server setting configuration problem